# Display 32Bit Unicode Character android

Tags: android, unicode, typeface

Am using [Entypo character map](http://www.entypo.com/characters/) in my App,  only few characters are getting displayed in Entypo fontface, which are 16-Bit Unicode Characters.

 ⌂ `&#8962;`

 ⚡ `&#9889;`

 ✉ `&#9993;`

I want to display 32-Bit Unicode Characters such as `&#59215;` `&#128266;`.

currently, am setting these strings in TextView from `strings.xml`.

**Code**

```
    Typeface symb = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Entypo.ttf");
    jfkfk.setTypeface(symb);
    kfhnf.setTypeface(symb);
```

***This is not webview***

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: for me this same issue